# Wordpress elementor pro Responsive mode doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, responsive, elementor

I'm trying to make responsive my website using elementor (pro version). I learned that whenever you modify something inside desktop mode/tablet mode or mobile mode, that edit works only inside the mode you worked in. But this is what heppens to me: I change something inside mobile mode, and that edit appears also in desktop and mobile. And viceversa. So what am I making wrong in order to keep responsive edit inside the respective mode? Thank you all

I tried to work on breakpoints but I dont know if I were correct

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of settings on Elementor that bring about global changes by default and will not be restricted to the device in question. A workaround would be using **custom CSS with media queries**. Read more here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Alternatively, you could also duplicate the entire container/section and take it from there: Let's say you want a container to look the same on desktop and tablet but you want to apply a different design or layout for mobile.

1. Open the navigator (Cmd+i), select the container and click "Duplicate"
2. Hide Container A on mobile --> visible on tablet and desktop
3. Hide Container B on desktop --> visible on mobile

It could also be an Elementor glitch. In that case, duplicating the **entire** page in your WordPress backend could help.

Hope this helps!

--
If you still need support, please also share what you are trying to change exactly so it's easier to find the error or perhaps provide you with the respective CSS. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmmm just be careful about this.
I have some trouble on my website about seo.

Some people on elementor say that youcan play with responsiv design like hide and not hide content on some device display.

But if you take a look on my website you will see home / office organiser title.
This one is create 4 time and ressponsive a lot , but if you look the website deeply with only txt you will see my text 4 times.
Https://www.organizalpha.com
I don’t know if its duplicate content or not .

Also be careful about this mod responsive…

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).